# Plotting a simple graph

Tags: python, matplotlib

I am trying to plot a simple graph using python. 
the code i used is as follows

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
plt.plot([1,2,3,4])
plt.ylabel('some numbers')
plt.show()
```

It throws me an error called (Import Error : NO module called _path)
the error message is as follows.,

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:/Users/s siddharth kumar/Desktop/graph2.py", line 1, in <module>
    import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
  File "C:\Python27\lib\matplotlib\pyplot.py", line 26, in <module>
    from matplotlib.figure import Figure, figaspect
  File "C:\Python27\lib\matplotlib\figure.py", line 24, in <module>
    import matplotlib.artist as martist
  File "C:\Python27\lib\matplotlib\artist.py", line 7, in <module>
    from transforms import Bbox, IdentityTransform, TransformedBbox, \
  File "C:\Python27\lib\matplotlib\transforms.py", line 35, in <module>
    from matplotlib._path import (affine_transform, count_bboxes_overlapping_bbox,
ImportError: No module named _path
```

Do i need to change the path of my running python in system variables or anything., ? I installed numpy,matplotlib and everything but still then I was not able to plot this simple values on the graph.

Comment: which os and matplotlib version are you running on? on my win7 and matplotlib 1.2.1, this works fine. Maybe building matplotlib on your own solves the problem

Comment: see: http://realiseyourdreams.wordpress.com/python-matplotlib/

Comment: It looks like one of the underlying cextensions did not compile correctly.

Comment: I am using Windows 7 enterprise (32 bit) Os and the version of matplotlib is 1.3.1

Comment: what is your file information..?! 
you need x and y axis to plot.

Comment: yes, I just want to plot these simple numbers on the x-y grapy(2-D) model.

Comment: Do i need to change the path of my running python in system variables or anything., ? I installed numpy,matplotlib and everything but still then I was not able to plot this simple values on the graph.

Comment: Can anyone help me out getting this.,

Comment: I can't reproduce this error. Does it also appear if you do not use `plt.ylabel('some numbers')`? Are these the only lines of code in your script?